# Проблема с Битриксом после переноса

Tags: mysql, битрикс

Перенёс битрикс с хостинга на хостинга, сайт функционирует нормально, но не проходит проверка mysql,вот что в логе:

```
2017-Sep-16 23:11:17 Функция getimagesize для swf (check_getimagesize): Ok
Успешно
2017-Sep-16 23:11:17 Версия MySQL-сервера (check_mysql_bug_version): Ok
Успешно
2017-Sep-16 23:11:18 Время на БД и веб-сервере (check_mysql_time): Ok
Успешно
2017-Sep-16 23:11:18 Режим работы MySQL (check_mysql_mode): Ok
Успешно
2017-Sep-16 23:11:18 Кодировка соединения (check_mysql_connection_charset): 
Ok
character_set_connection=cp1251, collation_connection=cp1251_general_ci, 
character_set_results=cp1251
Успешно
2017-Sep-16 23:11:18 Кодировка базы данных (check_mysql_db_charset): Ok
CHARSET=cp1251, COLLATION=cp1251_general_ci
Успешно
2017-Sep-16 23:11:19 Кодировки таблиц в БД (check_mysql_table_charset): Ok
Успешно
2017-Sep-16 23:11:19 Структура базы данных (check_mysql_table_structure): Ok
0% done
2017-Sep-16 23:11:19 Структура базы данных (check_mysql_table_structure): Ok
2% done
2017-Sep-16 23:11:23 Структура базы данных (check_mysql_table_structure): Ok
4% done
2017-Sep-16 23:11:31 Структура базы данных (check_mysql_table_structure): Ok
6% done
В таблице b_user_field_lang поле USER_FIELD_ID "int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT "0" 
" не соответствует описанию на диске "int(11) NOT NULL "
В таблице b_user_field_lang поле LANGUAGE_ID "char(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT "" " 
не соответствует описанию на диске "char(2) NOT NULL "
2017-Sep-16 23:11:33 Структура базы данных (check_mysql_table_structure): Ok
8% done
2017-Sep-16 23:11:34 Структура базы данных (check_mysql_table_structure): Ok
10% done
2017-Sep-16 23:11:34 Структура базы данных (check_mysql_table_structure): Ok
12% done
2017-Sep-16 23:11:34 Структура базы данных (check_mysql_table_structure): Ok
14% done
2017-Sep-16 23:11:34 Структура базы данных (check_mysql_table_structure): Ok
16% done
2017-Sep-16 23:11:47 Структура базы данных (check_mysql_table_structure): Ok
18% done
```

Как обойти вот это :

```
В таблице b_user_field_lang поле USER_FIELD_ID "int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT "0" 
" не соответствует описанию на диске "int(11) NOT NULL "
В таблице b_user_field_lang поле LANGUAGE_ID "char(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT "" " 
не соответствует описанию на диске "char(2) NOT NULL "
```

Answer (score 1):

Проверка говорит, что структура таблицы отличается от образцовой. В обеих случаях там добавлено значение по умолчанию для поля.
Нужно для этих полей ручками убрать его. Т.е. в свойствах таблицы удалить дефолтовые значения для полей. Или выполнить команду по типу ALTER TABLE.